# DNS resolv config

Tags: resolv.conf, resolvconf

Let me narrate you my small story:

So right now, I am using an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS distribution in my lab.
After installing Ubuntu, I tried just check my Internet access by googling.
However that was impossible. So firstly I try to ping Google's server:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

This first ping was successful. So secondly I try to ping yahoo site:

```
ping yahoo.com
```

The answer was that the name was unknown so I decide to check the resolv.conf
file in /etc:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search <www.some-sites>
```

The problem is the nameserver. My collaborators told me that the have copied some lines in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.config.d/base:

```
domain bla.bla
search <www.some-sites>
nameserver 111.222.3333.4444
nameserver 555.666.7777.8888
```

They proposed me to reboot or just run the following commands

```
resolvconf --enable-updates
resolvconf -u
```

When I checked /etc/resolv.conf it was again the same as that beginning

```
 Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search <www.some-sites>
```

So how I can input the domain and my two new specific nameservers???
I don't really know hot to configure interfaces and if it is possible.
I cannot also understand why this happened since base is a file that should be copied into resolv.conf file. Could you explain me why that error happened?

Thank you

Comment: Try changing `resolv.conf` manually and then do `sudo service network-manager restart`. If it works, we can see what else can be done. On a side note, make sure your organisation's firewall allows icmp packets to external sites

Answer (score 3):

NetworkManager is the program which (via the resolvconf utility) inserts address `127.0.1.1` into `resolv.conf`. NM inserts that address if an only if it is configured to start an instance of the dnsmasq program to serve as a local forwarding nameserver. That dnsmasq instance listens for queries at address 127.0.1.1.

If you wish to see witch `DNS` you use currently type command

```
nmcli device show <interfacename> | grep IP4.DNS
```

You can set different `DNS` param for each connection

If you do not want to use a local forwarding nameserver then configure NetworkManager not to start a dnsmasq instance and not to insert that address. In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq
```

and restart the NetworkManager service.

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

In this mode, NetworkManager updates `/etc/resolv.conf` (still via resolvconf) to include the nameserver addresses NetworkManager has for active connections.

If you want to disable the resolvconf mechanism for updating resolv.conf and just use a static resolv.conf file, do the following.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf  # Delete the symbolic link
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf   # Create static file

# Content of static resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate a bit on point to resources regarding the purpose / usefulness of this local forwarding nameserver provided by the `dnsmasq` utility?

Comment: The setting `dns=dnsmasq` is mainly useful for a VPN, where you might want some DNS queries to be sent over the VPN but not others. I'm not sure of the details.

Comment: nmcli must be installed from apt. If you cannot get the command to run, this is why.